# Determinant and trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find $\det A$ and $\text{Tr} A$ for the matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, where $p$ is a prime number or a  positive integer such that the square root is irrational number.

My attempt is described below. From hypothesis we know that
$$ \det(A-\sqrt[n]{p}I)=0,
$$ hence $ \det(A+\sqrt[n]{p}I)=0$ because the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$ has rational coefficients. Multiplying these two relation we get $ \det(A^2-\sqrt[n]{p^2}I)=0$ and so on.

From here, I don't find something. How to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that $n$ appears in $\sqrt[n]{p}$ and in $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, where in the last one I take it as the dimension (= number of columns) of the square matrix $A$. So the characteristic polynomial is a polynomial of degree $n$, with rational coefficients and with $\sqrt[n]{p}$ as a root:

\begin{equation}
p(\lambda)= \lambda^n + c_{1} \lambda^{n-1} +\dots + c_{n}
\end{equation}

Now each coefficient $c_{i}$ will be a function involving sums of monomials of degree $i$ constructed with $\sqrt[n]{p}$ and the other (possibly complex) roots. For example one can show that $c_{n}=\det(A)$ and $c_{1} = \text{Tr}(A)$. Now the key argument is that to get a rational number involving products of  $\sqrt[n]{p}$, you must at least raise it to the power $n$! This shuold imply that every coefficient is $0$ except from $c_{n}=p$. So you have $c_{n}=\det(A)=p$ and $c_{1} = \text{Tr}(A)=0$.

Now one should make this kind of argument sound by filling the gaps and proving every step. I hope that I've not made any mistakes and that this is helpful!

EDIT: Note that this argument depends on the fact that $\sqrt[n]{p}^k$ is irrational for all $k<n$

Comment: Since  $a$ defined by the square root of order $n$ of $p$ is an eigenvalue, we have that $p(a)=0$. Hence, $0=p+\det(A)\Leftrightarrow \det(A)=-p$. Am I wrong? Why is $c_n=p$?

Comment: Yes i think that was a mistake by my side, good job for spotting that! Have you checked that the other steps of my argument are sound? Let me know if my answer is of some utility  :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question misses details, otherwise there are many possible solutions.

Indeed, suppose that $p$ is an integer at the power $n$, let's say $p=a^n$, with $a \in \mathbb{N}$. Then any diagonal matrix, with rational coefficients and $a$ on the diagonal, has $\sqrt[n]{p}$ as an eigenvalue. Then you can have any trace and determinant you want...

Comment: Thank you for the answear. I made a mistake, actualy $p$ is a prime number or an integer such that the square root is irrational.